# "colormgr get-devices" returns empty list

Tags: 15.04, colors, color-management, gnome-color-manager

I've a fresh install of 15.04 on my laptop. I was trying to set up a color profile for my monitors using a Spider 4. When I open the color settings I get the message:

```
No devices supporting color management detected
```

[image]

So I tried to do it via command line using the `colormnr` command:

```
ted@laptop:~$ colormgr get-devices
ted@laptop:~$
```

As you can see the list is empty. Do you have any advice what could be wrong or how to solve this problem?

Both problems I didn't had with 14.04 I migrated from. I even can boot 15.04 from live cd install `colormgr` and don't face such problem. A reinstall is sadly not an option now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 (64bit). 
I did a fresh install without any other programs. Both, the graphical user interface from Gnome and "colormgr get-devices" (which propably both are using the colord daemon) returned an empty list for me.

But it only appears on gdm3. I installed lightdm from the repository, enabled it, and now colormgr and the GUI work fine.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: I have a U14.04 at work and one at home with different hardware and monitors. One uses Unity on gdm and one Gnome Shell 3.12 on lightdm. Both show the same error.