# "No devices supporting color management detected" for a notebook monitor

Tags: monitor, colors, icc

this didnt help me: ["colormgr get-devices" returns empty list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673368/colormgr-get-devices-returns-empty-list)

yes, colormgr returns empty list too.
the answer there is confuse, I have lightdm, it speaks about reconfiguring gdm that I have not.. (reconfigure lightdm did not work).

I go on app "System Settings/Device Color Profiles" (here is Colour.. anyway..) and I always get this: "No devices supporting color management detected"

ubuntu 16.04 (all latest updates possible are installed)

what can I do to try to fix this problem (I need it to show my notebook monitor so I can configure it)?
**1 - why my notebook monitor is not being detected, where can I check why it is failing?**

**2 - I need it because the screen white color is quite yellowish/ambar.**

the app "Color profile viewer" shows an option "Default: KENNEX" therefore, such notebook should be detected right? is there something I can do or could it be some kind of driver/detection bug?

I dont know if these can help?
`lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)  
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
```

`dmesg |grep vga -i`

```
[    0.132533] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[    0.132533] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.132533] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.132533] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    1.080171] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    2.818117] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    2.822288] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    2.829108] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
```

thx!

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was about the yellowish color.
I solved it with `redshift -O 15000` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/733390/589343).
Tho I like this `redshift -O 7500 -g 0.5:0.5:0.6` better (lowering gamma from 1.0 improved contrast too).

My monitor still doesnt appear on the list, and I dont know how to fix that, but I fixed the main problem here, so a proper full answer would still be better.